# Warning in Next.js 14 Project: "Internal React error: Expected static flag was missing. Please notify the React team. At MenuBar component."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, warnings, next.js13, tiptap

Is this warning something to worry about or has it been fixed already ?
Any help is kindly appreciated.

I searched the entire web for answers but none could be found.

My code:

```
import { Button } from "../components/ui/button";
import { FaListOl, FaListUl, FaUndo, FaRedo, FaCode } from "react-icons/fa";
import { BsEraser } from "react-icons/bs";
import useMyStore from "../app/(store)/store";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function MenuBar({ editor }) {
    if (!editor) {
      return null;
    }
  
    const { activeNote } = useMyStore();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      editor.commands.setContent(`
      <h1>${activeNote.title}</h1>${activeNote.content}`);
    }, [activeNote]);
  
    return (
      <div className="p-4">
        <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            onClick={() => editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()}
            disabled={!editor.can().chain().focus().toggleBold().run()}
            className={`${editor.isActive("bold") ? "is-active" : ""}`}
          >
            B
          </Button>
...
```